# How can I make the input stay as it is in the hover mode, when it contains any text?

Tags: html, css

**How can I make the input stay as it in the hover mode, when it contains any text in?**

I want to make the input box have any text in (like in email on image exemple) to look as when the mouse is hover the input box. How could I do this editing my css/html documents (or if I have to add an javascript what should I code?)

mouse not hover the email input:
[image]

mouse hover the email input(and how do I want when is text in any of the inputs):
[image]

**The code used:**

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>formulary animated</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <form>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="first_name"/>
            </div>  
            <div class="group">
                <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="last_name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" id="telephone"/>
            </div> 
            <button class="submitForm">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    background: #333;
    font-family: helvetica;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: .7em;
    font-weight: bold;
}   

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 40px;
}

.group {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px; 
}


input {
    top: 1px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #87ceeb;
    color: #fff;
    width: 16em;
}

label {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    background: #87ceeb;
    padding: 7px 4px;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    transition: top 1s;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
}

.group:hover label {
    top:  -24px;
}

.submitForm {
    border: none;
    background: #ff4500;
    padding: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 30px 6px 0;
    width: 40em;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #ba3c50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.submitForm:hover {
    top:2px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px #ba3c50;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery, there is a hover function built in

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/utxy967w/

**Code**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.group').hover(

               function () {
                  $(this).find("label").css("top","-24px");
               }, 

               function () {
                   if ($("input", this).val() == "") {
                  $("label", this).css("top","0px");
                   }
               }
            );
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest simply adding a class-name to the parent `.group` element, when the `<input>` element's value is no longer equal to the default value:

```
// binding the anonymous function as the change event-handler:
$('.group input').on('change', function() {
  // toggling the class-name of 'hasEntry' on the closest
  // '.group' element; adding the class-name if the <input>
  // value is *not* the default-value, removing it if the
  // the value is the default-value:
  $(this).closest('.group').toggleClass('hasEntry', this.value !== this.defaultValue);
});
```

Coupled with the CSS:

```
.group:hover label,
.group.hasEntry label {
  top: -24px;
}
```

```js
$('.group input').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.group').toggleClass('hasEntry', this.value !== this.defaultValue);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 40px;
}
.group {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
input {
  top: 1px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #87ceeb;
  color: #fff;
  width: 16em;
}
label {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  background: #87ceeb;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  transition: top 1s;
  -webkit-transition: top 1s;
}
.group:hover label,
.group.hasEntry label {
  top: -24px;
}
.submitForm {
  border: none;
  background: #ff4500;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 30px 6px 0;
  width: 40em;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #ba3c50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.submitForm:hover {
  top: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #ba3c50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="group">
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="first_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="last_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
      <input type="text" id="telephone" />
    </div>
    <button class="submitForm">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Where did you add the "$('.group input').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.group').toggleClass('hasEntry', this.value !== this.defaultValue);
});"?

Comment: If you click the 'Show code snippet' then you can see (and run) the whole code.